How can I move the selected faces inwards without creating new faces? I just want to shrink the face next to it inwards
as stated in the Title I want to reverse extrude the faces inwards without creating new faces, there should be a Shortcuts which I didn't catch in the Tutorial. Help would be really helpful


Just grab g :)

@DanielMöller G is extending the edges inwards, similar as you would solidify the selected faces

That means you got duplicated faces occupying the same place. Do a merge first (select all a, and merge m  by distance)

@DanielMöller thanks this helped
